# Orange Canvas: Regression models gives the r^2 coefficients out of [-1,1] interval

Tags: r, regression, data-mining, orange, coefficients

I am using the Orange canvas with its regression methods to make some estimations about my data set. The regression coefficients r^2 must be inside of the interval [-1,1] for being meaningful according to statistics field. But sometimes, I've got the regression coefficients -50,.. or 26,.. etc. So, I am confused about that. How can I interprete such the coefficients ? Thank you all already.

Comment: Maybe Orange is buggy? Have you double-checked the code, and compared to other tools?

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination):

> Important cases where the computational definition of R2 can yield **negative values**, depending on the definition used, arise where the predictions that are being compared to the corresponding outcomes have not been derived from a model-fitting procedure using those data, and where linear regression is conducted without including an intercept. Additionally, **negative values** of R2 may occur when fitting non-linear functions to data.

There is nothing in the [definition of R²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions) that theoretically prevents it from having arbitrarily negative values. I guess you can interpret -50 as even worse than -1. But with regard to R² = 26, I'm clueless.